# Problem converting JSON data into a Java Map

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson

I am experimenting with serializing and deserializing between YAML and JSON formats to/from Java objects. I am using the Jackson library to do the heavy lifting. I ran into a problem when trying to parse JSON into an object and came to the realization that JSON does not seem to support a map structure.

Here is the Java class:

```
public class MetricData {

  public enum Operation {
    INCREMENT, DECREMENT, SET;

    @JsonCreator
    public static Operation getType(String value) {
      return valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String value() {
      return name().toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  private Double              value;
  private Long                timestamp;
  private Operation           operation = Operation.INCREMENT;
  private Map<String, String> labelValues;

  // getters/setters removed
}
```

Note the field `labelValues`, which is a map with string keys and values.

I then set up a test JSON file and attempted to translate the JSON into a Java object.

```
{
    "name": "gitlab_pipeline_success_total",
    "description": "blah blah blah",
    "type": "counter",
    "labels": [
        "project",
        "something-else"
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 1.0,
            "timestamp": 0,
            "operation": "increment",
            "labelValues": [
                {
                    "project": "opoe"
                },
                {
                    "something-else": "junk"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "timestamp": 0,
            "operation": "set",
            "labelValues": [
                {
                    "project": "dex"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is valid JSON, but when I ran the program, I get an exception:

```
[ERROR] 2024-02-02 07:41:20.550 [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:851) - Application run failed
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.RuntimeJsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (File); line: 14, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.beastcode.devops.prometheusbroker.domain.Metric["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.beastcode.devops.prometheusbroker.domain.MetricData["labelValues"])
```

Is there a way to structure JSON such that it can be "converted" into the Java map structure? Or, looking at it from the other direction, should I refactor my class to be more JSON "friendly", and if so, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sample json is wrong please below json
{
"name": "gitlab_pipeline_success_total",
"description": "blah blah blah",
"type": "counter",
"labels": [
"project",
"something-else"
],
"data": [
{
"value": 1.0,
"timestamp": 0,
"operation": "increment",
"labelValues":
{
"project": "opoe",
"something-else": "junk"
}

```
    },
    {
        "value": 3,
        "timestamp": 0,
        "operation": "set",
        "labelValues": 
            {
                "project": "dex"
            }
        
    }
]
```

}